# Multilingual Custom Landing Pages in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, documentation-generation

I have a sphinx generated site with the following settings in my conf.py:

```
root_doc = 'contents'
html_additional_pages = {'index': 'index.html'}
```

This allows me to add a custom landing page in the `_templates` folder. Everything is working fine in my English project.

The issue that I am currently having is that I want to serve multilingual versions of my documentation site (e.g., English and German). Everything is working fine here, too, except for the landing page, which is always set to the default: English.

How can I set `html_additional_pages` in my `conf.py` to serve different landing pages depending on the language.

I though about adding something like this in my conf.py:

```
if "language = en":
   html_additional_pages = {'index':'index.html'}
elif "language = en":
   html_additional_pages = {'index':'index-de.html'}
```

But it's not working, unfortunately.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: See how to internationalize and translate your docs: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/. To see it in action, change the localization, for example Brazilian Portuguese: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/pt_BR/master/

Comment: @StevePiercy: Thank you very much! I managed to solve my problem with Jinja templating and the i18n extension.